# Step.js and Asynchronous Control Flow with CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I am trying to get Step.js library working properly with coffee-script. I am quite new to coffee but here is my attempt:

```
setTimeout(
  =>
    console.log("step 1 at #{new Date}")
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 2 at #{new Date}")
        setTimeout(
          =>
            console.log("step 3 at #{new Date}")
          10000
        )
      10000
    )
  10000
)

# step 1 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:18:51 GMT-0600 (CST)
# step 2 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:19:01 GMT-0600 (CST)
# step 3 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:19:11 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

should be the same as:

```
step(
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 1 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 2 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 3 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
)

# step 1 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:12:04 GMT-0600 (CST)
# step 2 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:12:04 GMT-0600 (CST)
# step 3 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:12:04 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

As you can see from the above example step is executing all the steps at the same time instead of doing them one at a time like it is supposed to. I am not too sure why that is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript implicitly adds a `return` in front of the last expression in a function. This is a problem with Step, which assumes that if you return anything, that step is synchronous.

The solution is to add an explicit `return` at the end of each step function:

```
step(
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 1 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
    return
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 2 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
    return
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 3 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
    return
)
```

Comment: Thanks you beat me to it ;). I like your returns with no undefined value it is cleaner. I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. So since coffee has implicit return statements it will return the value of the last statement (or expression if you will). Step library assumes that when you return an explicit value from the function you are doing synchronous stepping (making it easier to mix and match sync and async operations). This works great in Javascript, where we have explicit return statements.

A workaround is to always return undefined:

```
step(
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 1 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
    return undefined
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 2 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
    return undefined
  ->
    setTimeout(
      =>
        console.log("step 3 at #{new Date}")
        this(null)
      10000
    )
    return undefined
)

# step 1 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:38:51 GMT-0600 (CST)
# step 2 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:39:01 GMT-0600 (CST)
# step 3 at Tue Nov 13 2012 13:39:11 GMT-0600 (CST)
```